# How to start a python script in the background once it's run?

Tags: python, process, background

```
def main(self,argv):
    do stuff.......

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

When my script is run, how can I cause it to immediately run main() as a background process?
It will run to completion and outputs information to a file.

I forgot to say...the goal is to be able to run this on any OS.
I do not want to modify the way the script is called in the command line, I want the script itself to cause it to run in the background.

Comment: You want to run your script as a daemon ? check pypi from package that can help you with that : http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=daemon&submit=search , i never use anyone of those so i can't recommend anyone .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

easy:

```
$ python yourpythonscript.py &
```

The os will handle that for you ;) Of course, you will have to state if this is on windows or *nix.

If you are running this under windows, you might want to check the `cmd.exe` program - I think there is an option there for running its arguments as a background process...

Or if you are running this under linux machine, you can check the process by using `ps aux | grep yourpythonscript.py`

Comment: I'd like to note that it *really* pays off to learn the common unix command line tools. Even for windows developers like me: With cygwin on your dev box, tons of problems that surround your main development effort can be solved. New hot tools this week: `sed`, `uniq`, `sort` and `comm`.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, run the program using `pythonw.exe` instead of `python.exe`.

On Unix and MacOS, use the [Python daemon recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/278731-creating-a-daemon-the-python-way/) or the [`python-daemon`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/1.5.5) package.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Python [threading](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html) library. This will allow you to run main() in the background.

Comment: Threading isn't useful to put the whole process in the background.  The shell will block until the main process exits, so you need to fork off a new process.

Answer (score 0):

In linux You could use & to run it on background and if you want it to be run even if you close that shell use nohup command:
`nohup python yourpythonscript.py &`