# How can I run python script on Windows 7, with ability to enable/disable apperance of window and on taskbar?

Tags: python, windows, interface, taskbar

I found only [How to start a python script in the background once it's run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345298/how-to-start-a-python-script-in-the-background-once-its-run) and [how to run a python script in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783531/how-to-run-a-python-script-in-the-background) - but it is permanent and is not allowing switching to a normal mode.

I want to periodically check for some situation (change of website) and notify me once it happens - without appearing as window and taking space in taskbar all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a Windows SysTray App/Service using the [Python for Windows Extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)

Please see similar question: [How to build a SystemTray app for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494739/how-to-build-a-systemtray-app-for-windows)

This is by no means trivial, so please feel free to post follow-up questions of a more specific nature!

**Update:**

You may also find this 3rd-party module quite useful that seems to implement the hardest part of this for you as a reuseable library:

https://github.com/Infinidat/infi.systray

Example using `infi.systray`:

```
from infi.systray import SysTrayIcon
def say_hello(systray):
    print "Hello, World!"
menu_options = (("Say Hello", None, say_hello),)
systray = SysTrayIcon("icon.ico", "Example tray icon", menu_options)
systray.start()
```

Looking at the source code for `infi.systray` the nice thing about it is that it doesn't depend on `pywin32`. It uses `ctypes` which is available as part of the standard Python library.

Comment: Heh, and I wanted to use Python because I expected that it will take far less code than Java. Now I am unsure :)